# Windows Phone: Get Cellular Network Type 2g, 3g, Edge ?

Tags: c#, xaml, networking, windows-phone-8, cellular-network

`NetworkInterfaceType` doesn't give the cellular network type. Is there any third party library or inbuilt class that gives this information ?

Comment: [Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). So instead of asking some other resource, specify what problem you had and what you have tried to solve it.